# How to write a MapReduce Prog where the output of the Reducers goes to a single Reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How to write a MapReduce Program where the output of my Mappers with go to  Reducers and the Output of the Reducers to another Reducer but in this case there will be only one Reducer so all the key-value pair outputted will go to the same Reducer.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to achieve? Mapper->Reducer->Reducer? Is this what you want?

Comment: yes....Mapper->Reducer->Reducer(number of reducer should be 1)

Comment: you cannot do that in MapReduce, without a second mapper (in a new job)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want output from multiple reducers directly to another reducer, which is not correct. You will need another map reduce job, pass your reducers output to mapper and use single reducer to get a single output file.

Comment: correct. using another reducer would require the shuffle and sort phase, which is performed at the end of the map phase.